# Can a variable receive many types of data?

Tags: c++

Can you create a variable which enables the user to put any type of data like int, string ... and then the program prints a message which tells the user the type of data they entered?

Comment: Unsure what you really want, [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) might help.

Comment: You'd have to do most of the work yourself. When you read input, you have to decide in advance what kind of variable to store it in. You could do something like store input in a string and then test "does this represent a valid int? does this represent a valid float?" etc, but there isn't a built-in "what type corresponds to this input".

Comment: Sounds like you are describing [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)?

Comment: sounds like [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) and [`std::any::type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/type).

Comment: how would you distinguish if the user wants the string `"1"` or the integer `1` or the floating point value `1f` ? When the user only enters `1` it can be anything

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do something like this. But can you be more specific about your particular problem?

Comment: No, this is the first time I use a programming language.

Comment: Read about what happened when [Excel](https://www.theverge.com/2020/8/6/21355674/human-genes-rename-microsoft-excel-misreading-dates) tried to determine types from inputs.

Comment: `user to put` The nice thing about users, is they can only input characters. All they can input is strings.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to deduce the type of input for example:

```
#include <initializer_list>

int main()
{
    // std::initializer_list<int>
    auto A = { 1, 2 };

    // std::initializer_list<int>
    auto B = { 3 };

    // int
    auto C{ 4 };

    // C3535: cannot deduce type for 'auto' from initializer list'
    auto D = { 5, 6.7 };

    // C3518 in a direct-list-initialization context the type for 'auto'
    // can only be deduced from a single initializer expression
    auto E{ 8, 9 };

    return 0;
}
```

It's also possible to answer what type of data has been input:

[image]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int isint(char a[])
{
    int len=strlen(a);
    int minus=0;
    int dsum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(a[i])!=0)
            dsum++;
        else if(a[i]=='-')
            minus++;        
    }
    if(dsum+minus==len)
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}
int isfloat(char a[])
{
    int len=strlen(a);
    int dsum=0;
    int dot=0;
    int minus=0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(a[i])!=0)
        {
            dsum++;
        }
        else if(a[i]=='.')
        {
            dot++;
        }
        else if(a[i]=='-')
        {
            minus++;
        }       
    }
    if(dsum+dot+minus==len)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    char a[100];
    cin>>a; 
    
    if(isint(a)==1)
    {
        cout<<"This input is of type Integer";
    }
    else if(isfloat(a)==1)
    {
        cout<<"This input is of type Float";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"This input is of type String";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why is half this answer images of code?

Comment: I suppose when OP says "entered by the user" they mean input read from the console.

Comment: Using `bool` instead of `int` for return type of `isXXX` would make more sense.

Comment: I don't think `3...---..5` is a `float`.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thanx Nathan this example is a very good counterexample and will be used to improve the code

Comment: Rather than weak code to test `int` or `float`, use `strtoi(), strtof()` and check `errno` and the end pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a variable receive many types of data?

Sort of. A [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) can hold any one of a number of predetermined types, like `std::variant<int, double, float, Foo>`. The only problem is to figure out what type to put in it from the input a user gives.

One approach could be to read a line into a `std::string` and try to extract the data from that string into all of the types in the `variant` until one succeeds.

To do this, we can put the `string` in a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) (which is similar to `std::cin` but only contains the data you put in it) and then extract from that `istringstream` into a variable of each type in the variant. As soon as one succeeds to deplete the `istringstream` completely, we can call that a match.

If none of the types matches, we don't want to return anything that can be mistaken for a real value so we can put the `variant` in a [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) - which either holds a value or don't.

To help with the extraction from a `std::string` I've made a function template called `extract` who's template parameters are the types it should try to extract from the `string`. It'll return a `std::optional<std::variant<TheTypes...>>` with the result.

```cpp
namespace detail {
// a helper function that will try to extract into one type at a time recursively:
template<size_t I, class... Ts>
std::optional<std::variant<Ts...>> extract_helper(const std::string& str) {
    // the type to try to extract:
    using value_type = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>;

    std::istringstream is(str);     // put the string in an istringstream
    value_type var;                 // declare a varible of the current type

    // try to extract into var and check that the istringstream is depleted:
    if(is >> var && !is.rdbuf()->in_avail()) return {std::move(var)};

    // it wasn't value_type, try next if we've got more types to try:
    if constexpr(I < sizeof...(Ts) - 1) return extract_helper<I+1, Ts...>(str);

    return {};     // no type succeeded - return empty optional
}
} // namespace detail

// this the the function the user will use:
template<class... Ts>
std::optional<std::variant<Ts...>> extract(const std::string& str) {
    return detail::extract_helper<0, Ts...>(str);
}
```

With this you can let the user input something and check against the types you supply. You can use [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) that applies a callable to the `variant` where the correct type has been resolved.

```cpp
struct Line {  // A std::string wrapper to extract a whole line
    std::string str;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Line& l) {
        return std::getline(is, l.str);
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Line& l) {
        return os << l.str;
    }
};

// helper type for visitor
template<class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...;
};

int main() {
    for(std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
        // use the above `extract` function and try to match a few types:
        auto opt = extract<long long, long double, std::string, Line>(line);

        if(opt) {             // if this is true, we got a match
            auto& var = *opt; // a reference to the variant in the optional

            // use visit with the visitor helper `overloaded` to get the type
            // of input:
            std::visit(overloaded{
                           [](long long) { std::cout << "integer\n"; },
                           [](long double) { std::cout << "float\n"; },
                           [](const std::string&) { std::cout << "word\n"; },
                           [](const Line&) { std::cout << "line\n"; },
                       },
                       var);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Could not figure out what that was\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This would also work for user defined `class`es which can extract from `istream`s.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/37fbKe4hE)

Comment: With an input like `3` both `int` and `double` will match (and a custom type might match too). And `std::string` will match anything. So this doesn't seem to identify the user input at all.

Comment: @user673679 One will have to supply the types in priority order, like `int` before a `double` and `string` last so that `3` is identified as `int` and `3.14` as a `double` etc., but sure, it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

When taking input from `std::cin` with a stream input function, the compiler always has to know the type of the input.

e.g.:

```
int a = 0;
std::cin >> a;
```

This effectively calls a function with a signature like this:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, int& a);
```

That function interprets the characters on the stream as an integer, and attempts to convert those characters to an `int` value. (Which may succeed, or fail if the input doesn't actually represent an integer).

We can write our own functions like the above to convert from characters on the input stream to our own custom classes. However, the type must always be known at compile time.

---

Of course, we could simply read that sequence of characters as a string (i.e. a sequence of characters).

We could then write our own logic to identify and convert the type of value contained in the string. (e.g. If it's contained in quotes, it's a string. If it's only numbers it's an integer. If it's numbers and a decimal, it's a float). Note that this could get very complicated, and it's hard to be unambiguous (e.g. `12` could be interpreted as an `int`, a `float` or a `double`, or some custom type depending on what rules we choose).

As an example, [here are the rules about how C++ interprets integer literals in code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but as I know you can use templates to do something similar, or you can create an object that receives the information and tests whether it's an integer, or a float, or string or char etc. and save on different temporal variables, not the most efficient way, use templates it's better but at least is a solution.